# Issue in rounding a float to a precision

Tags: java

I am writing a function round:
static float round(float number, precision){}

The function should work like this: round(12.3456f, 3) = 12.345

My definition of function is like this:

```
public static float round(float value, int precision) {
float result;
if(precision <= 0){
    throw new RuntimeException("Precision can not be zero or less");
}

int number = (int) power(10,precision);
value = value * number;
result = (float)Math.round(value)/number;

return result;
}
```

But the issue is that, my unit test case for this function doesn't pass,

```
 public void mathTestNew() {
    assertEquals("MathTest",12.341,OOTBFunctions.round(12.3416f,3));
 }
```

The result is 
     **junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: MathTest expected:<12.341> but was:<12.342>**

I am not sure how to overcome this error. I am not sure if BigDecimal will help me in this.

Comment: As floats are not decimal types, rounding it will return the same bits. If this converted it to a string, then it seems reasonable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did want to use `BigDecimal`:

```
public static float round(float value, int precision) {
    if (precision <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Precision cannot be zero or less.");
    }
    BigDecimal decimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
    return decimal.setScale(precision, RoundingMode.FLOOR).floatValue();
}
```

You may lose accuracy when converting from `BigDecimal` to `float`, so if accuracy is a must, do not convert; keep the value as a `BigDecimal`.

As mentioned in other answers, [`float` is an approximation of a base 10 number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary). The following demonstrates just that:

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(12.3416f)); // outputs 12.34160041809082
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("12.3416"));    // outputs 12.3416
```

Answer (score 4):

Rounding normally occurs towards the nearest integer. So `12.3416` is *correctly* rounded to `12.342`

If you want the rounding behaviour you seem to be asking for (where the number is rounded down towards negative infinity) then you should use [Math.floor(x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) instead of Math.round(x)

Also be careful with rounding floats / doubles as they both suffer from numerical inaccuracy. If you really want high accuracy on decimal places, you may be better using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Comment: 12.3416 rounds to 12.342. The OP should use Math.Floor

Answer (score 3):

`Math.round` is "round-to-nearest".  You probably want `Math.floor`.

Answer (score 1):

`12.3416` rounded is `12.342`. There in lies your problem. You probably want `Math.Floor` instead. I would recomend against constantly multiplying as that can ruin the number. However, by 10 does not lower precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write such a method. Floating point doesn't have decimal places, it has binary places. Ergo you cannot round to a specified number of decimal places. If you want decimmal places you must use a decimal radix, i.e. BigDecimal, or DecimalFormat. Apart from the error in expectation noted by @ColeJohnson, code like you have written will fail in over 90% of cases.

Comment: He is converting the float to a string but with rounding.

Comment: @ColeJohnson He most certsinly is not. The method he is attempting to write returns a float. It cannot be done.